# ACR122U commands fail after reconnecting unless I wait for 2 seconds

Tags: java, nfc, mifare, apdu, pcsc

I'm having problem with the ACR122U reader when trying to run commands after a failed command and reconnecting. Take for example the following code I'm using to detect the type of connected tag:

```
private CardTerminal terminal; //ACR1222L or ACR122U
...
private void detectTagType(timeout: Long)
{        
    terminal.waitForCardPresent(timeout);
    Card card = terminal.connect("*")
    // Check the ATR bytes for ultralight values
    if (isUltralight(card.getATR().getBytes()))
    {
        try
        {
            // Runs the native GET_VERSION command (0x60)
            byte[] version = getDesfireVersion(card);
            // Check the version bytes for EV1 values
            if (isUltralightEV1(version))
            {
                // Is an ultralight ev1
            }
            else
            {
                // Another tag
            }
        }
        catch (MyNFCException exception)
        {
            // Possible UltralightC since it does not support the GET_VERSION command            
            // Reconnect to tag to wake up from failed command
            card.disconnect(true)
            Card cardC = terminal.connect("*") 

            // The code works if I add Thread.sleep(2000); here            

            // Try running the AUTHENTICATE command (0x1A) as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897813/distinguish-mifare-ultralight-from-mifare-ultralight-c
            if (tryRunUltralighcAuthenticateCommand(cardC))
            {
                // Is an ultralight C
            }
            else
            {
                // Unkonwn tag
            }
        }
}

// The following methods run the corresponding native commands wrapping them 
// as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542610/authenticating-ultralight-ev1-with-pc-sc-reader/42563617#42563617. 
// (Wrapping with them with the InCommunicateThru and the correct header depending on the reader, 
// i.e. {0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00} for the ACR1222L and {0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00} for the ACR122U)

private byte[] getDesfireVersion(Card card) throws MyNFCException 
{
    // Runs the GET_VERSION command and returns the bytes returned by the tag. 
    // If the tag does not support the command raises a MyNFCException 
}

private boolean tryRunUltralightcAuthenticateCommand(Card card)
{
    // Runs the Ultralight C AUTHENTICATE command (0x1A) and returns true if it succeeds and false if it fails
}
```

When I test this code with an Ultralight C tag and an ACR122U reader the AUTHENTICATE command (tryRunUltralighcAuthenticateCommand) I get {D5 43 01} as a result (i.e. timeout). However, if I run the same code with an ACR1222L reader and the same tag it works as expected, i.e. the command is successful. Furthermore, if I force my program to wait for 2 seconds (with Thread.sleep(2000)) after the reconnection it also works with the ACR122U reader as expected (but this is obviously not a solution).

I get the same behavior after any failed command with any tag. For example, if I try to authenticate an Ultralight EV1 with the wrong password, reconnect, and then run any command it will work with the ACR1222L reader but will fail with code {D5 43 01} on the ACR122U (unless I sleep my program for 2 seconds after the reconnect).

I have tried disconnecting without resetting the tag (card.disconnect(false)) and not reconnecting at all (in which case I get a CRC error {D5 43 02} after the failed command).

Is there something I am missing? Or any other workaround to this issue besides sleeping my thread for 2 seconds after every reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation/design of the ACS drivers; its just how it works. I have yet to find a way around this.